# Obtain First Entry for Each Month/Year Pair

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I wish to obtain the first entry of each month/year pair. I was thinking of structuring a groupby method but am unsure of how that would play out given the order of precedence.

```
     Date   Seconds
    2020-05 2748.03 
    2020-05 2748.25 
    2020-05 2777.72 
    ... ... ... ... 
    1997-12 100.22 
    1997-12  66.66
    1997-11  54.53
    1997-11  92.11
    1997-11  42.52
    1997-10 155.22  
    1997-10 115.03
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `groupby().head`:

```
# change `date` to your year/month column name
df.groupby('date', sort=False).head(1)
```

or `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.drop_duplicates('date')
```

Output:

```
      date    Value
0  2020-05  2748.03
3  1997-10   112.67
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that this is a list of strings like so:

```
dates = [
    "2020-05 2748.03",
    ...
    "1997-10 115.03"
]
```

In order to group by the year you first need to split the date into year and month column and seconds column like so:

```
dates = [single_date.split(" ") for single_date in dates]
```

dates list is now:

```
[
    ["2020-05", "2748.03"],
    ...
    ["1997-10", "115.03"],
]
```

Now you should build the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns =['year_month', 'seconds'], dtype = float)
```

Now lets groupby year_month and take the minimum in the seconds column

```
first_entries_per_month_year = df.groupby("year_month").min()
```

Hope that helped

Comment: don't forget to upvote so other people will see it too

Comment: I realized you actually used the "seconds" column as a proxy for sorting but the minimum of that data doesnt necessarily correspond to the first entry. I updated the info to reflect this. I also dont have the reputation yet to upvote but will do that once I get there!